# How to change one of the property linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to use linq to change one of the property in my list, but this didn't work, do not create a new variable(this is a simple example, actual List have many properties)

```
List<string> aaa = new List<string>()
        {
            "a", "b"
        };

        aaa.Where(o => o == "b").Select(o => {
            o = "c";
            return o;
        } ).ToList();
```

Comment: You have to assign this again to `aaa` as all LINQ-methods return a new collection, Btw.: your select is bit complicated, you may simply use `Select(o => "c")` instead.

Comment: In addition: if you have to change object properties (not value itself) I'd avoid to use LINQ, it's much more clear for the future reader if a QUERY doesn't change its input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ is a *query* language, you can 'ask' things, but it is hard to *modify* something using LINQ. And you shouldn't do that.

Changing an objects state in an enumerator is usually a bad thing, so consider to use a `foreach` loop.

If you want to change the output, rather than the actual elements, you can do this:

```
var list = aaa.Select(o => o == "b" ? "c" : o).ToList();
```

Comment: Decided to delete my answer which is basically (now) the same as yours. +1 anyway :)

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for that @HimBromBeere

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List<string> aaa = new List<string>()
        {
            "a", "b"
        };

aaa = aaa.Select(o => {
            return o == "b" ? "c" : o
        }).ToList();
```